# angular2 forms error - Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm creating a user registration for with ionic2 which contains a password field which is set to have a minimum length 10. When the characters is not up to 10 i'd like to show the user as the user types but i get this error on the page

```
Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined
```

HTML

```
<ion-item>
          <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" formControlName="Password"  [(ngModel)]="Password"></ion-input>
          <div *ngIf = "Password.hasError('minlength') && !Password.hasError('required')" class = "alert alert-danger">
            <span>Password should contain 10 characters</span>
          </div>  
        </ion-item>
```

JS

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                  username: [''],
                  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix Reactive and Template Driven forms. Complete example with Reactive Forms only:

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
     <div *ngIf = "passwordCtrl.hasError('minlength') && passwordCtrl.hasError('required')" class = "alert alert-danger">
       <span>Password should contain 10 characters</span>
     </div>  
 </ion-item>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  username: [''],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
});

get passwordCtrl() {
  return this.registerForm.get('password');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use `Password` to access the form control. You need to use

```
registerForm.controls.password.hasError()
```

**One more note.**

You have mixed two approaches - [**Template driven**](https://angular.io/guide/forms) forms and [**Reactive forms**](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). You have already used reactive forms, so remove `ngModel` part and let only `formControlName` with lowercase variant for `password`.

```
<ion-input type="number" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
```

and you can provide value for that control just using

```
registerForm.patchValues({
   password: "*****"
})
```